# centos httpd.conf multiple subdomain different location

Tags: wordpress, apache, subdomain, httpd.conf, vhosts

This has probably been answered but I can't find a straight answer, or the ones I found don't work.

I have one domain, let's call it mydomain.com The DNS settings point two subdomains. These are staging.mydomain.com and mydomain.com. Both have an A-record pointing to same IP, lets say 8.8.8.8.

On the server (8.8.8.8) I have httpd.conf with two virtual hosts, which already create by cpanel. These are as follows:

mydomain.com

```
<VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/userxxx/public_html

    ## User ydg015 # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        suPHP_UserGroup userxxx userxxx
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
        <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
           SuexecUserGroup userxxx userxxx
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
       RUidGid userxxx userxxx
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mydomain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mydomain.com combined
    # ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/userxxx/public_html/cgi-bin/
</VirtualHost>
```

And...

staging.mydomain.com

```
 <VirtualHost 8.8.8.8:80>
        ServerName staging.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias *.staging.mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /home/userxxx/public_html/staging

        UseCanonicalName Off
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/staging.mydomain.com combined
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/domlogs/staging.mydomain.com-bytes_log "%{%s}t %I .\n%{%s}t %O ."
        ## User ydg015 # Needed for Cpanel::ApacheConf
        <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
            suPHP_UserGroup userxxx userxxx
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_disable_suexec.c>
            <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
                SuexecUserGroup userxxx userxxx
            </IfModule>
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
            RUidGid userxxx userxxx
        </IfModule>
       # ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/userxxx/public_html/staging/cgi-bin/


        # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
        # Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/userxxx/staging.mydomain.com/*.conf"

    </VirtualHost>
```

The problem is:

I'm using wordpress multiple site to build both site (staging and main), and the multisite provide another subdomain like http://en.mydomain.com and http://en.staging.mydomain.com

Everytime I go to en.mydomain.com or en.staging.mydomain.com, I always land on "cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi" someone told me, maybe I should make a change on the http.conf, but I don't know what should I change.

can anybody help me to fix this?

Any suggestions would be so appreciated. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

The code given in these two virtual hosts are fine, but there could be another configuration in which might causing this behavior.
You should use following command to identify the correct document root.

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

**Note:** httpd needs to be replaced with correct executable for your environment, for example apache2 or apachectl

Share the output of this command in case if you still not able to understand the issue.